# How to provide default values for values in a Prometheus timeseries that are null

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

Me and my team want to write a PromQL query that is `true` every time a new Helm Chart is deployed in our K8S cluster, which we can use to create an alert. We are scraping Kube metrics, and are scraping the `helm.sh/chart` label from various K8S resources which allows us to see when new charts are released in Prometheus.

Using the following PromQL query, we get a count of how many instances of every chart is deployed:

`sum by (label_helm_sh_chart) (kube_deployment_labels)`

Putting this inside the `increase` function, every timeseries is only `true` (ie does not equal 0) when these counters increase, which happens to be when a new chart is synced:

`increase(sum by (label_helm_sh_chart) (kube_deployment_labels)[1m:])`

The issue we are facing is that when we deploy a new version of a Helm chart, the timeseries just *starts*: with `null` values leading up to the moment the chart is deployed for the first time; and then suddenly a count of how many times it is deployed. The `increase` function does not recognise a change from `null` to `n` as an increase. Similarly, the `change` function does not recognise this change as a change in value.

For example, we had a Helm chart, `rideshur-web-0.4.1`, which we had deployed 3 different services with. We made a change to the Helm chart and released it as `rideshur-web-0.4.2`. We deployed the `0.4.2` chart to replace all 3 of the `0.4.1` deployments. That created a graph in Grafana as follows:

`sum by (label_helm_sh_chart) (kube_deployment_labels{label_helm_sh_chart=~"rideshur-web-.*"})`

[image: Graph of Helm chart releases]

And using the increase function, it appears like this:

`increase(sum by (label_helm_sh_chart) (kube_deployment_labels{label_helm_sh_chart=~"rideshur-web-.*"})[1m:])`

[image: Graph of when Helm charts are released]

The main thing to notice is that the chart for `rideshur-web-0.4.2` does not fire on it's first release, which is crucial. We want to see that spike so we know when the chart was first released.

In short then, we need either:

1. A way to be able to identify in PromQL a change from `null` to `n`/not `null`
2. A way to be able to set all `null` values in a timeseries to some default, ideally `0`.

There are many StackOverflow posts, Medium posts & GitHub issues stating that if we add `or on() vector(0)`, this will provide us with default values of 0 in place of nulls.

This does not work for our query as our query will always have a value - because we are using `kube_deployment_labels{label_helm_sh_chart=~"rideshur-web-.*"}`, the wildcard means that as soon as the timeseries for `rideshur-web-0.4.1` reduces, the timeseries for `rideshur-web-0.4.2` begins to exists/increases.